# I set a button to add a bold line to a rich edit, but the first time I click the button it doesn't come out bold?

Tags: delphi

I have set a button to add a line(bold) to a rich edit, but the first time I click the button it doesn't come out bold?

Eg

> line1, **line2**, **line3**

Code:

```
red1.SelAttributes.Style := [fsBold];
red1.Lines.Add('   Name: ' + Edit1.Text);
```

Does anyone know what I have done wrong?

-Thanks

Comment: To modify the style of text, add the text, select the text, then set SelAttributes.Style and that will modify the style of the selecgted text. You clearly didn't do it in the right order, or read any documentation in docwiki?   http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomRichEdit.SelAttributes

Comment: *Does anyone know what I have done wrong?* I know what you did wrong. You didn't post the code that you used to create that output. Please fix your question.

Answer (score 2):

`SetAttributes` applies to the current selection at the current caret position.  What you have described will happen if the caret is not already at the end of the text when you call `Add()`.  `Add()` places the caret at the end of the new text, which is why subsequent calls to `Add()` pick up the new attributes (assuming the user does not move the caret).

To apply new attributes on any new line, you need to make sure the caret is at the end of the existing text and that there is no selection, then you can assign the new `SelAttributes` values and call `Add()` afterwards, eg:

```
red1.SelStart := red1.GetTextLen; // <-- add this
red1.SelLength := 0; // <-- add this
red1.SelAttributes.Style := [fsBold];
red1.Lines.Add('   Name: ' + Edit1.Text);
```

Then the new line will take on the new attributes every time.

If you do not want to change the user's current caret position+selection, you will have to save and restore those values:

```
OldSelStart := red1.SelStart;
OldSelLength := red1.SelLength;
try
  red1.SelStart := red1.GetTextLen;
  red1.SelLength := 0;
  red1.SelAttributes.Style := [fsBold];
  red1.Lines.Add('   Name: ' + Edit1.Text); 
finally
  red1.SelStart := OldSelStart;
  red1.SelLength := OldSelLength;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

To use `Lines.Add` to add text, you need to add the text first, set the selection up, and then use the selection's attributes on that text.

```
var
  OldStart: Integer;
  i: Integer;
  NewLine: string;
begin 
  for i := 1 to 3 do
  begin
    // Set the starting position to the end of the text
    OldStart := RichEdit1.GetTextLen;
    // Build the text to be added - you need the length later
    NewLine := 'This is line ' + IntToStr(i);
    // Add the line
    RichEdit1.Lines.Add(NewLine);
    // Set the start of the selection to the stored position
    RichEdit1.SelStart := OldStart;
    // Set the length of the selection, and bold it
    RichEdit1.SelLength := Length(NewLine);
    RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Style := [fsBold];
  end;
end;
```

However, if you're going to bold all of the text, it's much quicker (and easier) to just do it all at once:

```
// Select all of the text
RichEdit1.SelStart := 1;
RichEdit1.SelLength := RichEdit1.GetTextLen;
// Set the font style to bold
RichEddit1.SelAttributes.Style := [fsBold];
// Clear the selection and move to the end of the text
```

Comment: For the second part of your answer you can also use "RichEdit1.SelectAll"

Comment: "*You need to add the text first*" - no, you don't. When new text is inserted, it takes on the attributes already at the caret position being inserted at.  If there is NO current selection, like when inserting at the end of the RichEdit, you can set the attributes first, then insert the text afterwards, and it works fine. This is especially useful when using the `SelText` property to insert multiple text fragments using different attributes on the same line at one time.

Comment: @Remy:  Not if you're using `Lines.Add`, which ignores the SelAttributes, which is why I said you have to add the text first. (Just confirmed in Seattle 10.)

Comment: @KenWhite: `SetAttributes` applies to the current caret position/selection. `Add()` respects the attributes already active at the end of the text. Place the caret at the end of the text, change `SelAttributes`, and then call `Add()`, and the new line will respect the new attributes (I tried it in XE2 and Seattle, it works fine). If the caret is not at the end of the text when `Add()` is called, the new attributes are not applied to the new line, as expected. So, to set attributes on a new line, you can set `SelStart:=GetTextLen` first, then set `SelAttributes`, then call `Add()`. It works.